# Page Pilling or FullPage - How to make this scroll effect

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, fullpage.js, scrollpane

I know that it is not a very precise question, but I do not know where to start, I have an example which is the objective design, however I cannot find any solution and / or documentation to help me make this type of layout.

More specifically this is the scroll effect that I want to do, http://modern8.com/d5-process/

It should be noted that I have already tried with FullPageJS and I have not been able to recreate it, if you can see the effect consists of applying fixed and relative position according to the scroll but as I indicate, I do not know where to start.

I really appreciate the help you can give me.

Comment: You can start with inspection of their page - script is in their HTML. Your goal is to get an idea of how it is done, so you would be able to do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

The effect is the same as in [pagePiling.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/#page2) but pagePiling.js uses snap scroll so you'll snap to each section. There's no scrollbar.

The closer you can get with fullPage.js is by using the paid Parallax extension with `autoScrolling: false` (to avoid snap) and placing the whole content of the section inside the `fp-bg` element.

There's an article about it here.
https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-create-tumblr-website-effect/